# How to use a cURL request in NativeScript

Tags: curl, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript and I need to make a cURL request to a website. I know NativeScript is javascript (and nodeJS) but I still can't figure out how to make a cURL request with it. How can I make a cURL in NativeScript? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure, whether this is applicable for you, but you could use NativeScript HTTP Module to make HTTP Request - https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http